# Differenence performance of ConcurrentHashMap in tablet and Nexsus

Tags: java, android

Was used ConcurrentHashMap with Integer value as key and custom object as value in application. When app is executed, i observed in >kitkat version devices the map is sorted by keys in descending order where as in tablet with os version 4.4.2 it sorted by address of the value object. Can any one please make me understand on this?

Ex :In devices :
     {1, @3456}
     {3, @2345}
    In tablets :
     {3, @2345}
     {1, @3456}

Comment: Map is not sorted at all, you need to use version that is keeping ordering, like `TreeMap`. If you really need a concurent one take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap doesn't guarantee any order, not depending on device or version of OS

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can consider watch this [movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORgucLTtTDI&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=28), where [Colt McAnlis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332023/colt-mcanlis) give a good explication about Maps.

**[EDIT]**

**This video talk about**

Optimizing your Android applications performance has a lot to do with how you're managing your memory; And more often than not, issues here can come from using collections that may not be frugal when it comes to memory.

Comment: Please provide more context about these links as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: `Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`